# Constant variable might already have been assigned

Tags: java, exception

I really need help. Don't know how to fix this. I wanna load some constants from properties file. I think, that Catch with **FileNotFoundException** can be thrown only on the **properties.load()**. But IDE says that

```
VK_MIN_ID = VK_MIN_ID_DEFAULT;
VK_MAX_ID = VK_MAX_ID_DEFAULT;
MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE = MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE_DEFAULT;
```

this variables might already have been assigned. Where?
Full code:

```
private static final int VK_MIN_ID;
private static final int VK_MIN_ID_DEFAULT = 1;
private static final int VK_MAX_ID;
private static final int VK_MAX_ID_DEFAULT = 999_999_999;
private static final int MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE;
private static final int MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE_DEFAULT = 500;

static {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/vk.properties");
        properties.load(fileInputStream);

        if (properties.containsKey("vk.min.id")) {
            VK_MIN_ID = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("vk.min.id"));
        } else {
            VK_MIN_ID = VK_MIN_ID_DEFAULT;
        }
        if (properties.containsKey("vk.max.id")) {
            VK_MAX_ID = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("vk.max.id"));
        } else {
            VK_MAX_ID = VK_MAX_ID_DEFAULT;
        }
        if (properties.containsKey("max.users.to.parse.at.once")) {
            MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("max.users.to.parse.at.once"));
        } else {
            MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE = MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE_DEFAULT;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        logger.warn("Файл свойств отсуствует! Устанавливаем настройки по умолчанию...");
        VK_MIN_ID = VK_MIN_ID_DEFAULT;
        VK_MAX_ID = VK_MAX_ID_DEFAULT;
        MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE = MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE_DEFAULT;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Ошибка чтения файла свойств! Работа будет прекращена", e);
    }
}
```

Big thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java compiler doesn't see what we can see -- that the assignment to `MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE` is at the end of the `try` block, so that either it gets assigned there or in the `catch` block.  It sees a possibility that it gets assigned in the `try` block, an exception is thrown, and it gets assigned again in the `catch` block.

Use a temporary variable to work around this.

```
int temp;
try {
    // other code
    if (properties.containsKey("max.users.to.parse.at.once")) {
        temp = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("max.users.to.parse.at.once"));
    } else {
        temp = MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE_DEFAULT;
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // other code.
    temp = MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE_DEFAULT;
} catch (IOException e) {
    // You'll need to assign something to temp here too.
}
```

After the last `catch` block, then assign `temp` to your `final` variable, once.

```
MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE = temp;
```

This way you can keep `MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE` `final`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having a `try-catch`, and having values set in the `catch block`, you can replace all that with a simple `if-else`, and that will work without having to remove the `final`.  Something like this:

```
File f = new File("src/main/resources/vk.properties");
if (f.exists()) {
    // set values here from FileInputStream
    // ...
} else {
    // set alternate values here if the file is not found.
    VK_MIN_ID = VK_MIN_ID_DEFAULT;
    VK_MAX_ID = VK_MAX_ID_DEFAULT;
    MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE = MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE_DEFAULT;
}
```

**EDIT**

The reason why you can't assign the constants from the `catch` block, is because, even though ***you*** know that the exception will be caught before the values are set for the first time, the ***compiler*** doesn't know that for a fact.  It has to assume that the exception can be thrown anywhere in the `try` block. And so, from the perspective of the compiler, it is possible for the final variables to have been set before the exception is caught, so it gives you the error.

Comment: I think you just noticed, but you can only accept one answer on a question.  But when you reach 15 rep, you'll be able to upvote all the answers that you found useful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

```
    VK_MIN_ID = VK_MIN_ID_DEFAULT;
    VK_MAX_ID = VK_MAX_ID_DEFAULT;
    MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE = MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE_DEFAULT;
```

`VK_MIN_ID`, `VK_MAX_ID` and `MAX_USERS_TO_PARSE_AT_ONCE` are declared as [`final`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)#Final_variables), this means that once assigned you can't change their value. Remove `final` keyword.

Comment: I know that it's final. But I can't understand where did it assigned first time? I think this exception will be catched before any assignation. No?